# Android permission and gesture navigations

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am updating one of my old Android apps where a permission to write system settings is required as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));

startActivityForResult(intent, SYSTEM_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
```

This starts following activity where a user allows modifying system settings:

[image]

Things get weird when a device uses gesture navigation in Android 10. Performing a "go back" gesture or tapping the back button (marked on the screenshot) does not return to the application. The settings application is displayed instead.

When using a 3-button navigation or 2-button navigation a "go back" action returns to the application. The only way to get back to the application that seems to work with gestures is performing a gesture that switches between two recent apps.

I've tested this on the device with Android 10 (Android One) and with emulator.

Comment: "tapping the back button (marked on the screenshot)" -- that is the up affordance, and it is not supposed to necessarily return to the application. If the app you are in has some form of hierarchy, the up affordance moves you up in that hierarchy.

Comment: @CommonsWare: in this case it should always return a user back to the application. Only when using gestures it displays a system settings app.

Comment: "in this case it should always return a user back to the application" -- in the Settings app, I would expect the up affordance to traverse upward in the Settings hierarchy. I cannot explain why a system back gesture would do that, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare: is it possible to require such permission in a different way so a user could always return directly to the application?

Comment: Well, bear in mind that that there are hundreds of different editions of the Settings app, between Android OS versions and device manufacturer customizations. If you are expecting consistency across all of those, you are going to be very disappointed, particularly for a fringe scenario like yours. I would expect on some devices that `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` simply doesn't exist and raises an `ActivityNotFoundException`. I don't know of any other way to request the permission, though.